# Load Profile plot from Smart meter data

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, power-grid

In electrical engineering, a load profile is a graph of the variation in the electrical load versus time.

I am currently working on Smart meter data having reading an interval of 30 min i.e power consumption per 30 min. How could I plot the Load profile if I Know the sum of power consumed during 30 min not in continuous form.

Comment: Y against X with a line chart...

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the difference between any two readings, divided by the time between them. This gives the average load during that period.

Just keep in mind:

1. You only get average power over 30min, no shorter peak values etc.
2. If power consumption is low compared to the resolution of the read out numbers, you get some aliasing effect. Imagine a device drawing 1kW constantly. If the smartmeter has a resolution of 1kWh, you will get interleaved load values of 0kW and 2kW. You might get around this by averaging over consecutive readings. If power consumption is even lower, it might be better to look at the time beween two changes in read value.

Comment: If you have a year's worth of readings (17520) plotted on a chart to fit on an A4 paper, then there is no chance of seeing the difference between any two readings...

Comment: @SolarMike: Absolutely true, It seems I was too focused on something I did this week, where I have exactly this problem.